# Vectors of pointers C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have to create a list of vectors of pointers to class objects. However, It seems that upon initializing vectors, there is no content written into them.
Here's the code :

main.c

```
#include "circle.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
vector<Circle *>vectors(2);
vectors.push_back(new Circle("Circle1" , 4 , 0 , 0));
cout << vectors[0]->name << endl;

return 0;

}
```

circle.h

```
#ifndef CIRCLE_H
#define CIRCLE_H

#include <string>

class Circle
{
public:
    std::string name;
    int radius;
    int x;
    int y;

    Circle();
    Circle(std::string givenName, int givenRadius , int givenX , int     givenY);
    double circleLength(int radius);
    ~Circle();
};


#endif // CIRCLE_H
```

circle.cpp

```
#include "circle.h"
#include <iostream>


const double PI  =3.141592653589793238463;



Circle::Circle(std::string givenName , int givenRadius, int givenX, int  givenY)
{
    name = givenName;
    radius = givenRadius;
    x = givenX;
    y = givenY;
}

Circle::Circle(){

}

double Circle::circleLength(int radius)
{
    return 2 * PI * radius;
}

Circle::~Circle(){
}
```

And I'm getting empty output.

P.S : Thank you all for your help. The mistake was caused by the lack of theoretical knowledge. I thought that

```
vector<Circle *>vectors(2);
```

would allocate memory for two elements like in the array and when i start filling it up, the count would start from 0. My bad.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. You didn't show how you are initializing `Circle::name`.

Comment: It's in the push_back function.

Comment: Note that there're 3 elements in `vectors`; `vectors[0]` is not the one you expected.

Comment: @JackNickolson That invokes a constructor of the class `Circle`, however only a declaration of said class is visible. There are no code, visible in the question, that assigns the value, given to the constructor, to the `name` member variable.

Comment: You're dereferencing a NULL pointer with `vectors[0]->`. There are two of them in your array after construction; after the pushback there are three, and only the third is non-null. Why you'r initially sizing your array to That this doesn't crash on your is somewhat inconvenient. I don't know what your intent was with that `(2)`, but unless you wanted two null pointers in your initial vector, it doesn't make much sense there.

Comment: If the intent was to reserve some space in the vector upfront, you should construct an empty vector and call `vectors.reserve(2)`. After that the `push_back()` would work as expected, that is adding the 1st element to the vector instead of the 3rd.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> vector<Circle *>vectors(2);
> ```

This creates a `std::vector` with two elements, both initialised to `nullptr`.

> ```
> vectors.push_back(new Circle("Circle1" , 4 , 0 , 0));
> ```

This adds a third element, which is not `nullptr`.

Your vector now looks like this:

```
nullptr
nullptr
Circle
```

> ```
> cout << vectors[0]->name << endl;
> ```

This therefore attempts to dereference `nullptr`, which causes **undefined behaviour**. Anything can happen.

One way to fix this is to initialise the vector as an empty one:

```
vector<Circle *>vectors;
vectors.push_back(new Circle("Circle1" , 4 , 0 , 0));
```

---

Note that you should probably use `std::unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Circle>> vectors;
vectors.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Circle>("Circle1" , 4 , 0 , 0));
```

Your current code never calls `delete` to release the memory allocated by `new`. `std::unique_ptr` handles that automatically.

Comment: Maybe a comment about `vector::reserve()` would be helpful too. I believe this is what OP intended with `vector<Circle *>vectors(2);`

Comment: @zett42: Perhaps that was the intention, but why reserve space for two pointers?

Answer (score 3):

```
vector<Circle *>vectors(2);
```

You are creating a vector with two elements, the next call to push_back will put the element at **third position**

```
vectors.push_back(new Circle("Circle1" , 4 , 0 , 0);
cout << vectors[2]->name << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that really helped